# How to create a reflowable content from the PDF?

Tags: epub

I am going to developing an application, which is an epub. I have PDF files. I need to make those files as reflowable content(epub)... Then only the PDF files will be viewable in mobiles, tablets... etc.. Please suggest the solutions to make reflowable contents from the PDF...

Comment: what language does your aplication use? 
on which platforms should it run?
have you looked at: http://www.2epub.com/ before reinventing the wheel? or just: https://www.google.nl/search?q=pdf+to+epub+conversion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9ze8UuGbHsKG8Qf2yYHAAw

Comment: I am aware of that online tool. But, we are trying to create tool to handle image carrying pdfs. The mentioned tool not handling the images properly.

Comment: if there are embedded fonts with custom encodings in PDF file there will be no way to restore text information  => what would you reflow then? you may go with OCR in this case, however it doesn't have 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using an open source software, go with [Sigil](https://code.google.com/p/sigil/).

If you want to learn innards of how to create by hand, or some tool of your own, Follow this. (This is a one month course, So you will not get all the content in one day, though).

1. Create the folder structure.
   In a folder of your choice, create the following: META-INF (folder), OEBPS (folder), mimetype ( a file with exactly same name ).
2. Put **application/epub+zip** in the file mimetype. No spaces no lines.
3. Convert your PDF to text format. In Adobe acrobat, you will have file > export> .
4. Read the content from PDF, you will find some conclusions of how you can split them in to chapters or sub reading topics. Split according to the understanding of the book, and make so many text files.
5. Make sub folder structure. Make **Images**, **Text**, **Styles** (folders) **content.opf**, **toc.ncx** (files) inside OEBPS folder.
6. Put all your split files in Text folder created in step 5.
7. put all images extracted in pdf in **Images folder**
8. Put any styles (not describing here,) in **Styles** folder.
9. In the META-INF folder created in step 1, create a file called **container.xml** and fill with the following: `<?xml version="1.0"?><container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">  <rootfiles>    <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>  </rootfiles></container>`.
10. If you are able to do these many things sincerely, ping again, I would try to tell you what you should put in **content.opf**, and **toc.ncx** in created in step 5.

As an example, You can use some example from my site. Download from [here](http://digepub.appspot.com/) and use them with caution. Do not distribute.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let I will try your idea.

Comment: Sigil appears not to have pdf conversion support. Perhaps that feature has been removed in the last decade.

Answer (score 0):

We're opening up a beta for our web based pdf reflow viewer at the beginning of 2015. Feel free to sign up to be part of our beta test. More info here:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/reflow-pdf-documents.jsp

Comment: Does your reflow works with out desktop version licence ? What is the user case here ? How do I convert pdf to reflow documents ?